# Using express.Router with TypeScript and ESLint

Tags: typescript, express, eslint

Working on a TypeScript project with ESLint, I've created an `express.Router` with:

```js
const router = express.Router();
```

And got:

> A function with a name starting with an uppercase letter should only be used as a constructor.

Then I tried:

```js
const router = new express.Router();
```

And got:

> 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

I also tried adding annotation with `const router : express.Router = new express.Router();` but that didn't work either.

Is there anything I can do to satisfy ESLint, without loosening its configuration?